# bash: ApiPort.exe: command not found

Tags: .net, bash, powershell, api, portability

I am trying to create a diagram of my project with the help of the `ApiPort.exe.` and I am getting the error: `bash: ApiPort.exe: command not found`. How can I fix it?

Here is what I did:

1 I went over to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer#solution-wide-view). And clicked the `ApiPort repository` to download the `.zip` containing the `.exe`.

2 I unpacked the `.zip` into the `C:\Users\myname\Home\Apps\ApiPort` folder.

3 I opened the folder from bash and tried to run the command from the documentation [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer#solution-wide-view): `ApiPort.exe analyze -r DGML -f [directory or file]`.

4 I got the error.

[image]

Could someone help me figure out what am I missing here, please?

Running the command from PowerShell I am still getting an error:

```
ApiPort.exe : The term 'ApiPort.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ApiPort.exe analyze -r DGML -f "C:\Users\myname\source\rep ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ApiPort.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

[image]

Comment: This is a Windows exe file and so probably needs to be executed at Powershell/cmd level

Comment: Try `./ApiPort.exe analyze -r DGML -f ...`, but I'm not sure why you're trying to run this from bash. It's a Windows executable, run it from PowerShell or command prompt.

Comment: @IanKemp, addition of the forward slash helped. Thanks.

Comment: @IanKemp, I am able to run the command from both bash and PowerShell now. I prefer bash, because it is easier to interact with (at least for me) than with PowerShell.

Comment: I would expect that if you know bash, you would know that all commands have to be specified as relative paths unless they're on the system path...

Comment: @IanKemp, should I remove my question?

Comment: @IanKemp, I would expect the Microsoft official documentation to be legit. :D

Comment: @manymanymore Haha, touche! Yes, MSDN docs are often missing the fine details like this.